# How to add string to EditorGUILayout.ObjectField on the right side?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetChildsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    public Transform transform;
    List<Transform> allChildren = new List<Transform>();
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    Vector2 scrollPos;
    
    [MenuItem("Get Childs/Get")]
    static void Init()
    {
        GetChildsEditorWindow window = (GetChildsEditorWindow)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(GetChildsEditorWindow), false, "Get Childs");
        window.Show();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(20);
        transform = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform to get childs", transform, typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Start"))
        {
            allChildren = new List<Transform>();
            ObjectLevel(transform);

            for (int i = 0; i < GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>().Length; i++)
            {
                var t = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>()[i];
                var level = ObjectLevel(t);
                names.Add(" Level " + level.ToString());
                allChildren.Add(t);
            }
        }

        if (allChildren != null && allChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            scrollPos =
                EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(400), GUILayout.Height(400));
            for (int i = 0; i < allChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                allChildren[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(names[i], allChildren[i], typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }

    public static int ObjectLevel(Transform current, int level = 0)
    {
        if (current.parent) return ObjectLevel(current.parent, ++level);

        return level;
    }
}
```

The result :

[image: levels]

I want the Level 3 all the levels and numbers to be on the right side of the ObjectField instead on the left side like in the screenshot.

Comment: Can't test but I'd start with `allChildren[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(allChildren[i], typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;` `EditorGUILayout.LabelField(names[i]);` to not use a label for the field and put a label on the right`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
And EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

```
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
allChildren[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(allChildren[i], typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;
EditorGUILayout.LabelField(names[i]);
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

[image: on the right]